# How to read and write to the same excel file in Talend in the same subjob?

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

I have a sub job that reads from an excel file and then uses a `tMap` to edit some of the rows and then outputs it to another excel file. I need to be able to read and write to the *same* excel file. Is this possible? Maybe there is a component that I don't know about that can store what is in the `tMap` and in another sub job I can write that content to the same excel file?
[image: my subjob]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by add a step.

You need to output in another Excel file in the first step.

Then subjob OK

Then input your temporary file in the first one.

Then delete the temporary file.

```
TInputExcel (first file) -> tmap -> toutputexcel (Tempory file)
|
subjob ok
|
TInputExcel (temporary file) -> tmap -> toutputexcel (first file)
|
tfiledelete (temporary file)
```